# Как в concat вставить строку после поля

Tags: sql, mysql

В sql запросе вставляю через concat

```
SELECT t.*, CONCAT('page/', uri) as uri
```

урлы получаются типа page/testovoe-uri
а как можно получить урл такого типа testovoe-uri/page

Comment: одни эмоции =))))

Answer (score 1):

все оказалось проще

SELECT t.*, CONCAT('', uri ,'/page') as uri